# E.coli fermentation - process flow

Tags: molecular-biology, ecoli, fermentation

I have an engineering background and have been assigned a project to look into to failures during E.coli fermentation process using the data available before/during/after the process

I have learnt some of the procedures involved in the process from SIP/ CIP and few things about inoculation during fermentation. But I am still lacking some basic knowledge of E.coli fermentation process using glucose and other media components. I consider and value these steps with extreme care during this project.

Any suggestions for resources from where I can learn about this process at a more basic/ intermediate level without focusing too much on any individual step.

I have looked at this youtube video and found it helpful to understand the fermentation process but I am looking into E.coli fermentation in particular, so I have posted my question here. I learnt a good deal about what OD measurement is, d0<sub>2</sub> values, KLA etc. during this project. I am looking for resources or suggestions to understand how these parameters affect E.coli fermentation process

[Bioprocessing Part 1: Fermentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eKdZ0dVCCo)

I also browsed through BiFlo reactor product pages to try to understand some basic information about E.coli fermentation.

[E. coli Fermentation Using a BioFlo® 110 Bench-Top Fermentor](http://www.knbs.co.kr/pdf/BioFlo110_ApplicationsEcoli.pdf)

I can provide more information if it helps anyone to provide some suggestions. I don't have biology background. So I am not aware of any decent textbooks or papers to read about E.coli fermentation process

Thanks